# Test whether value exists within array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I have an array of objects and I would like to test it to determine whether a property with a certain value exists (at least one occurrence) and for it to return a boolean value to indicate the result. I'm using the Ramda library and have been experimenting with the `has` function to try and achieve this, however this only returns a boolean on whether the actual property exists and not it's respective value.

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 10004,
        name: 'Daniel',
        age: 43,
        sport: 'football'
    },
    {
        id: 10005,
        name: 'Tom',
        age: 23,
        sport: 'rugby'
    },
    {
        id: 10006,
        name: 'Lewis',
        age: 32,
        sport: 'football'
    },
];
```

Checking the array of objects for `sport: 'rugby'` should return `true` and `sport: 'tennis'` should return false.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this function:

```
function myFind(data, key, value) {
    return data.some(function(obj){
        return key in obj && obj[key] == value;
    });
}
```

Reference: [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: @dandavis. I've seen a javascript there... should I delete my answer?

Comment: seems unclear if ramda is a requirement or just something OP has tried

Comment: fair enough, leave it up and solicit further feedback; OP could have been clearer.

Answer (score 12):

If you're looking for a Ramda solution, this would do fine:

```
R.filter(R.propEq('sport', 'rugby'))(data)
```

[`R.has`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#has), as you noted, just checks whether an object has the named property.  [`R.propIs`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#propIs) checks whether the property is of the given type.  [`R.propEq`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#propEq) tests whether the property exists and equals a given value, and the more generic [`R.propSatisfies`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#propSatisfies) checks whether the property value matches an arbitrary predicate.